# Union not working in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have written below UNION code in mysql but it is not working.

Please help.

```
SELECT * FROM (`am_glmaster`) WHERE 
`logid_status` IN ('DISPATCHED','DELIVERED', 'COMPLETE') 
 AND `dispatch_from` =  'New Delhi'
UNION SELECT *
FROM (`glmaster_history`)
WHERE `logid_status` IN ('DISPATCHED', 'DELIVERED', 'COMPLETE') 
AND `glmaster_history`.`dispatch_from` =  'New Delhi'
```

> Giving error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'WHERE `logid_status` IN ('DISPATCHED',
>   'DELIVERED', 'COMPLETE') AND `glmaster_h' at line 4

Comment: Also check number of columns and Name in both tables are same

Comment: Solved. Problem was due to brackets

Comment: Can i know why my question down voted.

Comment: If some one down vote then give proper reason why is he down voting. So  next time i will not make mistake.

Comment: Don't expect a reply. The most annoying thing about Stack Overflow is how common anonymous downvotes are. I recommend that you don't take it personally. There's bound to be someone who wants to downvote you just for using SQL.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Bill Karwin

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM 
        am_glmaster 
    WHERE 
        logid_status IN ('DISPATCHED','DELIVERED', 'COMPLETE') 
    AND 
        dispatch_from =  'New Delhi'
UNION 
SELECT *
    FROM 
        glmaster_history
    WHERE 
        logid_status IN ('DISPATCHED', 'DELIVERED', 'COMPLETE') 
    AND 
        dispatch_from =  'New Delhi'
```